# How to split 6.3 to 0.3,1.3,2.3,3.3,4.3,5.3,6.3 in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there any  elegant way to input a float 6.3 and output float array {0.3,1.3,2.3,3.3,4.3,5.3,6.3} in C# ?

Given input a float a.b , if a = 5, b=3 , then I need a float array {0.3,1.3,2.3,3.3,4.3,5.3}

```
input:3.2  -> a float 
output:{0.2,1.2,2.2,3.2} -> a float array
```

Comment: What kind of "split" is that supposed to be?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you want to do here...

Comment: I think the question is something like: Given `a.b` how do you get from `0.b` to `a.b` - So if `a = 8` and `b = 2` then `0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2, 6.2, 7.2, 8.2`

Comment: Yes ! @Belogix you are right !

Comment: split always need a DELIMETER for apply split on something.Is "," is your delimeter? or How do you want to split this?

Comment: @ShawnZhang then please edit and change your question according to your requirement so make it understandable for others

Comment: so that's a class assignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
float f = 6.3f;
float[] ff = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Math.Ceiling(f))
    .Select(i => (float)Math.Round(i + (f - (int)f), 1))
    .ToArray();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/fXO7F7)

```
0.3
1.3
2.3
3.3
4.3
5.3
6.3
```

Comment: This is how I like it - a short one-liner that nobody understands :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this:

```
double originalNumber = 6.3d;
double integralPart = Math.Truncate(originalNumber); // this is now 6.0
double fraction = originalNumber - integralPart; // this is now 0.3

List<double> results = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i <= integralPart; i++)
{
    double newNumber = i + fraction;
    results.Add(newNumber);
}
```

I have tried this and it works - it creates a list from 0.y to x.y for a given fractional number.

Answer (score 2):

My version:

```
float[] getFloatStuff(float num) {
    float[] arr = new float[(int)num + 1];

    for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        arr[i] = num--;

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: That's a nice one, too :-D

Answer (score 1):

Well, the "perfect answer" for this question is:

```
float[] MyFunction(float arg)
{
    if (arg == 6.3)
    {
        return new float[]{0.3,1.3,2.3,3.3,4.3,5.3,6.3};
    }
    if (arg == 5.3)
    {
        return new float[]{0.3,1.3,2.3,3.3,4.3,5.3};
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Not defined what to do in such situation");
}
```

Please remember, the answer always is of the same quality as question =).

Comment: In a way, one can learn a lot from that answer about real software-developer life...

Comment: Yeah, Unfortunately I often see such code and even more often - such requirements =((. Just wanted to point out that not defined question leads to not defined answer =). By the way, how others guessed what was required in other cases - it could be completely other case, not guarantees... Even math says we can't build full sequence from 2 test cases

Answer (score 0):

I don't know really, but something like this ?

```
private static List<float> Test(float input)
    {
        var list = new List<float>();
        while (input> 0)
        {
            list.Add(input);
            input--;
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There you are:

```
var arr = GetElegantRange(f).OrderBy(_ => _).ToArray();

public static IEnumerable<float> GetElegantRange(float input)
{
    while (input > 0)
        yield return input--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinQ to do this:

```
static float[] Function(float value)
{
  var max = (int)value;
  var remainder = value - max;

  return Enumerable.Range(0, max).Select(n => n + remainder).ToArray();
}
```

Don't forget to add

> using System.Linq;